# Issues with a Twitter Bootstrap 3 gird layout for large, medium and small screens

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a grid layout using Twitter Bootstrap 3, but I can figure out why there is a big gap between my columns when its viewed on a large screen.

Here is the demo of what ive got and what the issues are:

http://jsfiddle.net/jSURG/18/

Even with the row class added i still get the big gag when there is lots of content added into area 2

```
<div class="container">    
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <section class="panel">area 1</section>
    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <section class="panel panel-info">area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br />area 2<br /></section>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <section class="panel">area 3</section>
        <section class="panel">area 4</section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try fiddling with the push and pull classes. I don't see how you can do it, but good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. You didn't wrapped them into row class.
2. the sum of numbers after col-lg- and col-md- should be less than 12 ine one row.

Comment: even with the row class when i add in lots of content in area 2 i still get the same issue with the big gap

Comment: two col-md-12 in one row is much. they should be col-md-6(for example), 12 + 12 = 24 > 12.

Comment: Hi, not following, sorry. If you have a look at this then resize you will see what i mean about the gap when viewing on large screen. The big gap between area 1 and 3. But when on medium screen i need them stacked 1,2,3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your columns in

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <section class="panel">area 1</section>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <section class="panel panel-info"></section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
            <section class="panel">area 3</section>
            <section class="panel">area 4</section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get the same issue when i add long content into area 2. In your code above if you add area 2<br /> lots of times the gap is there! Thats the problem im having

Answer (score 1):

From [Bootstrap - Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> **Introduction**
>   ...
>   - Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding...

and

> **Grid options**
>   ...
>   Gutter width    30px (15px on each side of a column)

But as you can see later in **LESS mixins and variables**

```
padding-left: (@gutter / 2);
padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
```

the gap is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter bootstrap's grid system isn't fluid, cascading or whatever you want to call it. It accepts only 12 columns on a row and you should use those .row wrappers around each 12 column element. I think that when it goes over it, it assumes that new row has started.

So with your grid, there's already one row with area 1 and area 2 (6 + 6 = 12) and the last .col starts a new row. And div.row acts like a div, it goes on top of the other.

You could try using something like Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/), with or without bootstrap. With bootstrap you could create the Masonry grid inside of row > col-lg-12 like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Masonry grid here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to the second div, area 2, something like

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   .div-lg-right {
        pull-right;
    }
}
```

I've tested the pull-right DOES works, just didn't test this css.